# hint on solving $1+y'^2-y\cdot y''=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following ODE: $$1+y'^2-y\cdot y''=0$$

I've never solved an ODE where two "versions" (don't know the term) of $y$ are multiplied with eachother, in this case $y$ and $y''$.

**Can I have a hint how to approach this, without too much of an answer?**

Answer (score 7):

Substitute $v(y)=\frac{dy}{dx}$, treating $y$ as the independent variable. Therefore, we evaluate $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ to be:
$$\frac{d^2 y(x)}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\right)=\frac{dv(y)}{dx}=\frac{dv(y)}{dy}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv(y)}{dy}\cdot v(y)$$
Hence, applying the substitution gives:
$$1+v^2-y\cdot v\cdot \frac{dv}{dy}=0$$
This is clearly a separable differential equation:
$$\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{1+v^2}{v\cdot y}$$
Solving this for $v(y)$ and substituting back for $v(y)=\frac{dy}{dx}$ should not be a problem.

Comment: What ends up is a double exponential solution for $y$ based on $v=\sqrt{Ay^2-1}$, right?

Comment: I'm trying not to read the entire answer, in order to solve for myself, but what does $v(y)=y'(x)$ even mean? $y$, as a variable, is not in the term $y'(x)$, right? So it seems to me that $v$ is not a function of $y$. The only way I can make sense of $v(y)=y'(x)$ is if I think of $v$ as the derivative operator. Or do you mean that we should plug in the inverse function of $y$, to get $x$ and plug that into $y'(x)$? i.e. $v(y)=y'(y^{-1}(y))$. This assumes $y$ is invertible, which we don't know, right?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Indeed, this is what I obtain.

Comment: @Programmer2134 If I understand your question correctly, note that $y$ is a function of $x$. Therefore, $v$ is also a function of $x$. I wrote $v(y)$ so that we could interchange the role of the dependent and independent variable during the substitution.

Comment: This is what confuses me: if $v$ is a function of $y$, and $y$ is not invertible (say $y(x)=x^2$), then $v$ doesn't have the information to generate $y'(x)$. For example, if $y=1$, then $v$ doesn't know whether $y=1$ because $x=1$, or because $x=-1$. if $x=-1$, then $y'(x)=-2$, but if $x=1$, then $y'(x)=2$. So when $v$ gets as input $y=1$, then how does it know whether to output $-2$ or $2$? That's why I cannot see how $v(y)=y'(x)$ makes sense, unless $v$ is a functional that takes the function $y$ and outputs its derivative, in which case it would just be the derivative operator.

Comment: @Programmer2134 : If you can apply this trick of experimentally finding a first order ODE out of the second order ODE, you can also directly apply the resulting transformations. In this case the separation $\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{y'y''}{1+y'^2}$ which integrates to $\ln|y|=\frac12\arctan(y')+C$ or $y'=\tan(C+\ln(y^2))$.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach. Treat this differential equation as an equation where $x$ is a function of $y$. The differential equation becomes:

$$1 + \frac{1}{x'^2} + \frac{yx''}{x'^3}=0$$

or equivalently:

$$x'^3 + x' + yx''=0$$

Now, substitute $z(y) = x'$

The differential equation becomes:

$$z^3 + z + yz' = 0$$

which is a seperable differential equation.

Note that you will have to solve another differential equation once you solved for $z$, but this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that $y(x)$ is invertible, which we don't know beforehand? if $y(x)$ is not invertible, we cannot see $x$ as a function of $y$, right?

Comment: If $y'$ is constant zero, then the equation becomes $1=0$ which clearly is impossible. So $y$ is locally invertible almost everywhere.

Comment: So this approach would not work if $y$ hadn't been invertible? Also, why do we care whether $y$ is locally invertible almost-everywhere? Shouldn't we require it to be completely invertible?

Comment: Ideally, yes. But in most cases one strives to find as much information as possible. So one is satisfied finding a local functional equation or ODE of lesser order that quite possibly extends to a not quite so local relation.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Solutions in the forms $y=y(x)$ and $x=x(y)$ are just two particular, very special ways, to parameterize [the first integral](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/First_integral) $F(x,y)=C$ of the system. In general, one may try the parameterization $(x(t),y(t))$, which increases the dimension, but adds freedom, since $y$ does not have to be invertible. All we need is that the gradient of $F$ is nonzero on the level set $F(x,y)=C$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll elaborate a bit on the substitution $v=y'$ in @projectilemotion's answer.

In general, differential equations with nonlinear dependence on lower derivatives are quite difficult and often not possible to solve analytically, so people use different tricks or try to guess a form of solution. In this equation
$$
y\cdot y''-(y')^2=1\tag{Eq}
$$
the LHS looks like the numerator in the quotient rule for
$$
\left(\frac{y}{y'}\right)'=\frac{(y')^2-y\cdot y''}{(y')^2}=-\frac{1}{(y')^2},
$$
however, in this form it does not give much. Let's try to replace the denominator with something more general - a *function of $y'$* - and see what we can get out of that
$$
\left(\frac{y}{f(y')}\right)'=\frac{y'\cdot f(y')-y\cdot f'(y')y''}{f^2(y')}\stackrel{(\rm Eq)}{=}\frac{y'\cdot f(y')-(1+y'^2) f'(y')}{f^2(y')}.
$$
If we manage to find $f$ such that the numerator is zero then we are (almost) done. It looks like a differential equation for $f$ if we treat $y'$ *as a variable* $v$, i.e. if $f$ solves
$$
vf(v)-(1+v^2)f'(v)=0
$$
then the numerator is zero if we set $y'$ as $v$. Solving it for $f$ we get one solution to be $f(v)=\sqrt{1+v^2}$, hence, the original solutions can be found among 
$$
\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\right)'=0.
$$

### P.S.

If you get this equation as the *Euler-Lagrange equation* within calculus of variations context then you can use [the standard way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) to get around the difficulty you've faced here.